# Can Hidden controls be focusable?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have some custom controls to simulate cell-like behaviour, i.e., one control for edition and another for display. In edit mode, one of them is hidden and the other is visible. Out of edit mode, it's the other way round.

The edit control is focusable, the display control is not.

What I really intend is to enable tab navigation to work properly.
I tried hooking a function to the GotFocusEvent from the edit control to force edit mode, but it doesn't work.

I wonder if making the control hidden also makes it non-focusable...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hidden or Collapsed controls are not focusable. If you want them to still be focusable, you can instead set their Opacity to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Control.TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex.aspx) property to set an order for Tab navigation. When a control is hidden or collapsed, it is not considered in the Visual Tree of controls so it is non-focusable. If you want to get focus on the display control, just place over it other transparent control that can receive focus and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have a custom control that when in focus should switch to edit mode.

What you need to do is handle the focus event on your custom control (rather than on the inner edit control).

Create two viewstates, one for edit mode and another for display mode, and use the logic in your focus event handler to set the viewstate accordingly once your custom control gets focus.